# how to convert this String to Dictionary in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

```
"{Sunday:0,Monday:1,Tuesday:1,Wednesday:1,Thursday:1,Friday:1,Saturday:0}"
```

I have been trying to convert a string to a dictionary but its giving an error of data is invalid.

Comment: Use `components(separatedBy`, `Scanner` or Regular Expression

Comment: Seems like a pseudo JSON. How did you get that?

Comment: @Kuldeep This is not JSON (keys are not in double quotes).

Comment: @Kuldeep i have already try that solution and its giving me error of data is invalid format

Comment: I reverted the last edit because it *invalidates* the question

Comment: The data is not in proper format

Answer (score -1):

**your json should look like this:**

```
"{\"Sunday\":0,\"Monday\":1,\"Tuesday\":1,\"Wednesday\":1,\"Thursday\":1,\"Friday\":1,\"Saturday\":0}"
```

**and then you can use this func**

```
            func convertToJsonReturnDict(string: String) -> [String:Any]? {
             guard let data = s.data(using: .utf8) else { return [:]
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                return json

            } catch {
                print(error)
                return [:]
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you run the code with the given string? It will `catch`. And never print `localizedDescription` in a JSON decoding context. Printing just the `error` shows you the real error.

Comment: ok thank you if adjusted the code and found the problem with the string :)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't answer the question if the string is as-is.